# Sinon.js, only stub a method once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, sinon, stub

I am wondering is there is a possibility in sinon.js to stub a method only once?

For example:

```
sinon.stub(module, 'randomFunction', 'returnValue/function');
```

In my test this *module.randomFunction* will be called multiple times *in the same test*, but I only want the stub to trigger once and then restore it so the function goes back to its normal behaviour.

Simulation of the real code:

```
myModule.putItem(item, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    // do stuff
    return callback();
  } else {
    // do other stuff
    return callback(null, data);
  }
});
```

The first time I want to trigger the error, the other times I just want it to continue the real flow.

Is this possible in sinon?

Kind regards,

Jimmy

*Edit:* I posted a solution I found for my problem based on the answer of @Grimurd

Comment: Modified to explicitly mention that the stub gets called multiple times *in the same test*.

Comment: Added a more realistic example.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible. Assuming you are using mocha as your testing framework.

```
describe('some tests', function() {    
    afterEach(function() {
        sinon.restore();
    })

    it('is a test with a stub', function() {
        // This gets restored after each test.
        sinon.stub(module, 'randomFunction', 'returnValue/function');
    })
})
```

Check out the [sinon sandbox api](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.5.0/sandbox/) for more info.

**UPDATE**

To answer your actual problem,

```
describe('some tests', function() {
    afterEach(function() {
        sinon.restore();
    })

    it('is a test with a stub', function() {
        // This gets restored after each test.
        sinon.stub(module, 'randomFunction')
            .onFirstCall().returns('foo')
            .onSecondCall().returns('bar')
            .onThirdCall().returns('foobar');
    })
})
```

Documented on http://sinonjs.org/docs/ search for stub.onCall(n)

Update 2: Since v5 sinon now creates a sandbox by default so it's no longer necessary to explicitly create a sandbox. [See the migration guide from v4 to v5 for more information](https://sinonjs.org/guides/migrating-to-5.0.html)

Comment: I probably did not phrase it correctly, but I meant that the stub gets called multiple times in the same test.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

```
sandbox.stub(module, 'putItem')
  .onFirstCall().yields('ERROR')
  .onSecondCall().yields(null, item)
```

Based on the answer of @grimurd I managed to get it working with 'yields'. Yields triggers the first callback function it finds in the original method signature.

So on the first call I basically say `callback('error')` and on the second call I say `callback(null, item)`.

Somehow I do wonder if callback would have been a better method name than yields ;)

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 4):

The other answers seem to ignore a key part of the question: "I only want the stub to trigger once **and then restore it so the function goes back to its normal behaviour**".

The following stubs the given method once, and then reverts back to the previous behavior:

```
let stub = sandbox.stub(module, 'method')
    .onFirstCall().returns(1)
    .onSecondCall().callsFake((...args) => {
        stub.restore();
        return module.method(...args);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the most helpful answer actually. Though I wonder, why there's no simpler way of achieving it. For example, in Jest it behaves like this by default, without the need to restore a stub after the first call.

Answer (score 4):

IMO there **is** a simpler way to achieve the expected behavior. From the docs:

> `stub.callThrough();`
> Causes the original method wrapped into the stub to be called when none of the conditional stubs are matched.

So, a real example would be:

```js
let stub = sandbox.stub(module, 'method')
  .onSecondCall().returns('whatever');

stub.callThrough();
```

Notice that the original method will also be executed by the **first** time it gets called.